# How to use Google Drive in a Java Desktop app?

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api

I am dealing with mobile and desktop applications. I am trying to use Google Drive as a permanent storage folder.  Unfortunately I am at a loss because I cannot find any examples.  Can someone point me at an example of storing or retrieving a file from Google Drive?

I would really like to see a simple example in code or maybe a library which can handle this.  I am stuck at Retrieve and Use OAuth 2.0 Credentials  https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Comment: can you show me an example please i want to integrate it in my java app please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the sample app on the drive API page?

*edit*

google moved the [examples to github](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/java)

Comment: that appears to be a fixed "bucket" for many people to access your project's drive.  I want an API to use the User's drive to store my application's data for access on another device.

Comment: @AdamOutler those Tutorials explain how to use the App engine to create an App (DrEdit) so the user can access __their__ own Drive.

Comment: can anyone please update the link ! it is expired and I want to same thing in my app .help please

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I figured out your problem. What I have understood is that you are looking for a way that makes you able to work on the same project from different computers.

If so, you simply have to download Drive. Once install it will ask you what folder you want to keep syncronized with Drive. If you select your workspace, it will be syncronized with Drive. So, on another pc, if you have installed Drive, you will be able to use the workspace folder too, with the same files.

I hope this is helpful.

Marco

Comment: I need this function integrated into my app, not a 3rd party, or official app.  I need to get the files generated from my program onto the user's drive.  I need a login and useage API.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Documents List API.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)

The Google Drive API & SDK are meant to be a mean to integrate applications into the Web-UI of Google Drive. To protect the security of the user's files, it puts some restrictions to the application developer, like:

- The app has to be installed from the Chrome Web Store
- The app can only access files created from the app itself,
- or files selected by the user using the Google Picker UI.

All these restrictions make the Google Drive API not a good choice for most non-web applications.
E.g. installing the app from the Chrome Web Store is probably something you would find cumbersome to request from your users for a mobile or desktop application. Nonetheless, without being installed from the Chrome Web Store your application will always receive an error when accessing a file from Google Drive.

The [Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) allows you to store and load files (not only Google Documents!) into Google Drive.

Comment: That looks like the practical case. But it seems that Google has plans to allow services to access the API. In the scenarios here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#scenarios it looks like it would be supported for a desktop app or service to access Google drive. I am trying to solve a similar issue, currently looking into this to see if it helps https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little bit old, still. You can look at this example: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

They do the OAuth2 for accessing task. But I just used the same code to access the files using the v2 API. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

I only retrieved the file list, but it is working (from .NET, desktop app).