# Desktop application unable to work with Google Drive?

Tags: java, netbeans, google-drive-api, desktop-application

The application I have developed is a file encryption software based on AES and TwoFish encryption. It all works well but I have been asked to allow the user of the computer to upload or save the files on the google drive storage account online.

The way my desktop app works currently is that the user will need to log into the system with username and password and based on their username and password entered will be used to log into their google drive account (Yes, I know this is not practical, but for now its just how I want it to work until I find a better method of doing so).

I have a few problems in terms of understanding the coding that is displayed on Google developers web pages.

The first problem I am having is to **connect my java desktop application to the Google drive account**. I need some coding that is explained (even just with a few comments) that I will be able to understand and manipulate so I can get it to work for my desktop application.

Coding for the Uploading of the file to Google drive, below:

```
private static InputStream FileDownloadFromCloudDrive(Drive service, File file) {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
      try {
        HttpResponse resp =
            service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                .execute();
        return resp.getContent();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // An error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      // File contains no contents that is on the Drive.
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The apparently the with this coding from a couple of sites and places say that it only returns part of the file and some information. Can anyone help me with this coding for understanding it and helping me correct it in any way.

Coding for displaying a list of the files from the google drive account:

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list();

    do {
      try {
        FileList files = request.execute();

        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
  }
```

Hope this will work, just need to display it somehow at a later stage like in a textarea.

So overall, I need help with coding to connect to Google drive for allowing to upload a file to the drive account. Last thing I just need some help with is what is required with the connection coding such as Google drive api or sdk (how to install and what is needed from it)

I really need the help as digging through the internet and differnt sites has just confused me.
Any help and coding will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887074/how-to-use-google-drive-in-a-java-desktop-app

Comment: Is there any way that you can help with me out any further with my problwm. My major problem is connecting to gooe drive. Please help me out with coding as struggling to understand it :(